# Easiest way to make sure a lot of threads finish in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm creating a lot of threads:

```
(1..255).each do |n|
  Thread.new do
    sleep(10) # does a lot of work
  end
end
# at this point I need to make sure all the threads completed
```

I would've hoped I could add each thread to a `ThreadGroup` and call a function like `wait_until_all_threads_complete` on that `ThreadGroup`. But I don't see anything obvious in the Ruby docs.

Do I have to add each thread to an array and then iterate over each one calling `thread.join`? There must be an easier way for such an extremely common use case.

```
threads = (1..255).map do |n|
  Thread.new do
    sleep(10) # does a lot of work
  end
end
threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
end
```

Comment: "Do I have to add each thread to an array and then iterate over each one calling thread.join" - yes. This is generally always how you'd handle it, regardless of language.

Comment: `threads.each &:join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use ThreadGroup#list

If you assign threads to a ThreadGroup with [ThreadGroup#add](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/ThreadGroup.html#method-i-add), you can map [Thread#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-join) or other Thread methods onto each member of the group as returned by the [ThreadGroup#list](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/ThreadGroup.html#method-i-list) method. For example:

```
thread_group = ThreadGroup.new
255.times do
  thread_group.add Thread.new { sleep 10 }
end
thread_group.list.map &:join
```

This will only join threads belonging to *thread_group*, rather than to ThreadGroup::Default.